# Firebase does not generate token for one device

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm developing an android application that uses firebase cloud messaging.

There is one single device (Android S10 - Android 10) that is giving me some headache.

Original flow:

1 - MainActivity:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
```

2 - NotificationService:

2.1 - `onNewToken`

2.2 - save token at room database for future use

3 - When user logged, send the token to the API

4 - API starts sending PUSH NOTIFICATIONS for that token

This flow works for all other tested devices (Motorola x4 - Android 8 , Motorola One Zoom - Android 9 , Samsung S9 - Android 10, Samsung S20 - Android 10), but for some reason it does not work at this S10 when the APK is signed and compiled for release.

For debug reasons, tried to change bunch of code.
Changed:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
```

To:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```

no effects on any device

Tried to add the code below in the MainActivity' `onCreate`:

```
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }
            //save token for future use here
        });
```

no effects

Tried to delete the instaceId before calling the code above:
`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();`
no effects too

The only way I could retrieve a firebase token for that phone was when I used the code above (`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(...);`) in my `Application.onCreate()`

That wouldn't be a problem if it worked at all.

Tried to send a push notification for this token retrieved from `Application.onCreate()`, but it never receives it.

I'm using all the latest libraries versions

Tried to put the line below in the proguard configuration:

`-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, is this problem still happening. Would you please confirm if the device is a Galaxy S10 or Galaxy S10e?